# How to chain constraint with parse PFQuery

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

Have a problem chaining constraint with parse PFQuery.

What i want :

I want to get all the photos around 50 km ordered by publication date. Latest first. (orderByDescending("createdAt")

If i don't put the location constraint, everything works good, as i have all my photos oredered by date.

When i put the whereKey for location, results are still ordered but for some reason, i can't have all the photos, some are skipped, and when i refresh, i never get the same result...

This is my code :

```
    var findPosts:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserPost")

        findPosts.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: location, withinKilometers: 50)

        findPosts.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        findPosts.limit = 10
        findPosts.skip = timeLineData.count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from your last comment I think you're going to have to create a cloud code function to do this.

You'll need to write it in Javascript. The website has a load of documentation of how to create it.

You can create a function called something like `nearestPosts` and then have a parameter like `skip` and `limit` and `location`.

Except now, instead of relying on the `PFQuery` to do everything for you you can build the logic yourself.

So you can do something like...

1. Fetch all the posts within 50 km of the location.
2. Sort the posts in order of `createdAt`.
3. Take the first `limit` number of posts starting after `skip`.
4. Return these posts in an array.

Essentially it is doing what you want to do but you have to do it manually.

Then in iOS you can do something like...

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"nearestPosts"
                   withParameters:@{@"limit" : @10, @"skip" : @20, @"location" : geoPoint}
                            block:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
   if (!error) {
     // posts array contains the posts you need
   }
}];
```

There's lots of documentation of how to do stuff with Javascript on the [Parse website](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide).

Your Javascript will be something like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("nearestPosts", function(request, response) {
    var location = request.params["location"];

    getNearestPosts(location).then(function(posts) {
        response.success(posts);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});

function getNearestPosts(location) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var query = new Parse.Query("UserPost");

    query.withinMiles("location", location, 50);

    query.find().then( function(results) {
        promise.resolve(results);
    }, function(error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

This will get all of the posts within 50 miles. And is just a start in how to get this all working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmcastel Actually, I got that the wrong way around. Your code should work. When you say "it isn't working" what exactly do you mean by "not working"? Docs here... https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo-query/iOS

Comment: I mean that the geo query is workin since all the post are within 50 km but i can't have them ordered by descending createdAt.

Comment: No sorry, i inverted, my problem is i get the post ordered but i don't have all the posts that are within 50 km. Also when i trigger agin and again, i never have the same result ?

Comment: Hmm. Can you show more code. How are you creating the location geopoint?

Comment: Yes i can but i know it s not a location issue since when i print it, the location is ok.

Comment: OK, please could you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Ok i edited my post to let you understand what i want to achieve.

Comment: i finally understood. This is the limit = 10. It takes the 10 closest photos and then apply the ordering. So if my limit is > to the photo count in the 50 km radius, everything is working. I need this limit to make my pagination..what to do ?

Comment: Ah OK! That makes sense :D In that case I think you're going to have to create your own cloud code function.

Comment: Waou great, i think i m a little "under level" for doing this. I don't know javascript...only swift. I will try.

Comment: @jmcastel edited my answer to show how to get started with this. You'll need to go through the "Parse Cloud Code Installation" stuff to be able to put the cloud code up onto your app.